# Why sigaction says that signals sent by keyboard shortcuts come from PID 0?

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, signals

I am doing dome investigations regarding signals handling.
In this particular case, I am interested in SIGTSTP on Linux (3.0.101 on SLES 11). Wrote a small program that catches SIGTSTP and prints its parent PID and the PID of the process that sent the signal.

This is what I see:

If I use kill -TSTP then the sending process PID is the PID of the shell where I ran the kill command, as expected.

If I type ctrl+z in the shell, the PID of the sending process is 0 but I expected the PID of the shell in which I pressed ctrl+z (and I ran the catcher program)

Anyone knows why this is happening? Shouldn't 0 be the PID of some special kernel-only processes? Sigaction's documentation tells that signals sent by kill will fill si_pid field but it doesn't mention shell shortcuts. Maybe si_pid=0 means "unspecified sender".

This is my catcher program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

void tstp_handler(int num, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    pid_t ppid = getppid();
    printf("\nReceived TSTP. pid %d ppid %d\n", info->si_pid, ppid);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_sigaction = tstp_handler;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &action, NULL);

    printf("Registered\n");
    printf("My PID is %d\n", getpid());
    while(1) 
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: Thou shalt not `prinf` from signal handlers.

Comment: You don't "type ctrl-z in the shell". Ctrl-z is interpreted by the line discipline of the tty/pty you're on. So most likely it's the kernel that will be sending the TSTP.

Comment: @alk: I know, but in this case the only purpose of the handler is to tell me who sent the signal

Comment: @Art: yes, perhaps I should have written "hit ctrl-z in the keyboard". stty says susp = ^Z so I assumed that the shell would send the signal to the process

Comment: @Patrik stty tells you how the kernel interprets what it sees on the tty, it has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: @Art: but then what happens when i hit ctrl-z? bindkey tells me
"^Z"           ->  tty-sigtsusp
so I assumed that the shell catches the ctrl-z and sends a signal to its child process

Comment: When you press ctrl-z, the tty code in the kernel sends TSTP to the process group for which this tty is the controlling tty.

Comment: When you're running a program in the foreground, the shell is not reading your keystrokes; it gets out of the way and just waits for the program to exit or get suspended.

Comment: a signal handler function in C has only one parameter, an `int` that will contain the number of the signal. so this is not correct: `void tstp_handler(int num, siginfo_t* info, void* context)`  You might want to read: <http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/> for an example

Answer (score 1):

Please [consult the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rt_sigaction.2.html) regarding `struct siginfo`:

> `si_signo`, `si_errno` and `si_code` are defined for all signals.
>          (`si_errno` is generally unused on Linux.)  The rest of the struct may
>          be a union, so that one should read only the fields that are
>          meaningful for the given signal [...]

Nothing says that `info->si_pid` is active and that you're allowed to read it. Your test code is meaningless.

Reading on, you discover that sending a signal with `kill` *does* fill in the `si_pid` field, which is why you see the correct PID when you send the signal with `kill`.

Comment: I read it and it states that si_pid is active for signals sent by kill, which makes my code meaningful because it was designed to catch signals sent by kill. My assumption was that hitting ctrl-z will do whatever "tty-sigtsusp" implies and then call kill somewhere

Comment: @Patrik: But you're *not* using `kill` in the case in question. Assumptions don't get your code to work.

Comment: @Patrik you are right and theres is no way calling it meaning less
It the behaviour of the os and want to know about it what is wrong with that ?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Yes, I am not using it. I assumed that the shell would do it for me because, to the best of my knowledge, a signal can be sent with the kill command, the kill() function or a keyboard shortcut so, what happens when a signal delivery is triggered by a keyboard shortcut? Sill I can know whether the signal came from kill or not

Comment: @Anjaneyulu: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: i guess linux kernel internally uses `kill()` for generating signals

Comment: @Anjaneyulu: No. `kill` is a system call used for userspace to call into the kernel. The kernel does not have to use that to talk to itself.

Comment: @Patrik: You *don't* usually know where a random signal comes from, so querying the PID is not generally possible or meaningful. You *can* however set up a particular discipline in which you do know what you're doing, e.g. when two of your own processes send each other SIGUSR1 via mutual kills. The facility *can* be used in certain circumstances, but that doesn't mean that it is *always* meaningful.